# slow server response time Amazon EC2

Tags: django, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I recently used the pagespeed insight tool because my website was loading slowly and one of the problems was "Reduce server response time. In our test, your server responded in 2.8 seconds." I read through their suggestions, but was not able to reduce the server response time.

I am hosting a django web application on my ec2 instance. I don't think there's any issue with my apache configuration, which I put below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Alias /static /home/ubuntu/project/static_root_content
    <Directory /home/ubuntu/project/static_root_content>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/ubuntu/project/fantasy>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                    Require all granted
            </Files>
    </Directory>
     WSGIDaemonProcess project python-path=/home/ubuntu/project:/home$
WSGIProcessGroup project
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/project/fantasy/wsgi.py
```

I am testing the site right now, so the web traffic is close to zero...

If I can provide any other additional details, please tell me. Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: 
1[CPU Usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7veBz.png)

Comment: What is your EC2 instance type? Is it directly connected to the internet? i.e. no reverse proxies, load balancers, etc.

Comment: t2.micro and yes it is directly connected to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

`t2.micro` instances are not very fast instances. On top of that, your CPU may be throttled based on your CPU credits that you've accumulated.

To increase the page speed, you can change your EC2 instance type to something stronger, such as a `t2.small`, `t2.medium` or even try an `m4` type.

Comment: I've used a t2.micro instance before and the server response time was not slow...it loaded pretty quickly and wasn't an issue when I used pageinsights on the other t2.micro instance.

What does it mean for the CPU to be throttled? How would I check that and what could I do to remedy it if it is a problem?

Comment: Take a look at the CloudWatch metrics for your EC2 instance. Look at the CPU metrics and Credits metrics. The T2 instances are burstable if you have the credits. If you don't, then your CPU will max out below 100%. Depending on the complexity of your web application, if you don't have credits and you need CPU, you won't get it. Also, the T2's CPU is shared. So you can only burst if the CPU capacity is available. Simple remedy: compare the performance of your app on a `t2.micro` with a `t2.small` and see if it gets better.

Comment: I added a screenshot of my CPU balance at the bottom of the question. Am I maxing it out?

Comment: The credit balance looks OK. It may be the `t2.micro` performance. Try a stronger instance type.

Comment: I changed the instance type to t2.small and there is no difference in average performance time. 

I tried to do a little bit debugging and the TTFB delivery is very slow. Any idea how to fix that?